# link error with cpp-7 version 7.5.0 asan

Tags: 18.04, gcc

My ubuntu18.04.4 LTS system just updated my cpp-7 package from 7.4.0 to 7.5.0 .
Now I get a link error when building with asan:

```
undefined reference to `__asan_version_mismatch_check_v8'
```

My command-line parameters are identical to what they were when the target was 7.4.0 and address sanitizer gave me excellent assistance.

for what it's worth...

While I'd love to be able to try to re-activate 7.4.0, the update process apparently removed it from my system:

```
apt-cache policy cpp-7
cpp-7:
  Installed: 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04
  Candidate: 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04
  Version table:
 *** 7.5.0-3ubuntu1~18.04 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     7.3.0-16ubuntu3 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic/main amd64 Packages
```

packages.ubuntu.com lists a 7.4.0 version (https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=gcc-7) but I haven't figured out how to get that onto my machine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by uninstalling cpp-7, then re-installing it.
First I ran `apt-get --purge remove cpp-7`; then I followed instructions for installing gcc.